# Table header inside another table header in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

[image]

I am trying to insert table header inside another table header. Above is how it looks like. I want the Update and Delete tab to get rowspan applied. I  almost got it how I wanted, but before Update col the table border is not properly closed. Please correct me there.

```
<table class="datatable table-striped table-bordered"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">ID</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Name of the Liquidated Society</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Jurisdiction of the Society</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Liquidation Order No & Date</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Name & Designation of Liquidator</th>
                <th colspan="6" class="text-center">In the Liquidated Society</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Update</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Delete</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>Govt Share</th>
                <th>Govt Loan</th>
                <th>Assets to be recovered</th>
                <th>Liability to be discharged </th>
                <th>Cancellation Order Number and Date </th>
                <th> Surplus amount remitted to CDF</th>
                </tr>


        </thead>

    </table>
```

I want heading starting from `govt share` to `Surplus amount remitted to CDF` under the heading `In the Liquidated Society.`

Comment: Not valid HTML code, `<tr>` is not allowed inside `<tr>`. Can you post an image of how you want it to look?

Comment: It has to do with your CSS. As you can see in my picture the border is proper. Try to check the CSS in `firebug`. Maybe there you can find why it is not closing properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here how you will do it

```
<table class="datatable table-striped table-bordered"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name of the Liquidated Society</th>
            <th>Jurisdiction of the Society</th>
            <th>Liquidation Order No & Date</th>
            <th>Name & Designation of Liquidator</th>
            <th colspan="6">In the Liquidated Society</th>

            <!-- here you have inserted the row, which is wrong -->

            <th>Update</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>

         <!-- created a new row -->

         <tr>
          <!-- buffer of five columns to reach your desired column -->
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>

           <!-- add columns below -->   

              <th>Govt Share</th>
              <th>Govt Loan</th>
              <th>Assets to be recovered</th>
              <th>Liability to be discharged </th>
              <th>Cancellation Order Number and Date </th>
              <th> Surplus amount remitted to CDF</th>

             <!-- add buffer of 2 columns -->
               <th clospan="2"></th>
            </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

What you were doing wrong was, you have started a `new row` inside a `row` that have two more `columns` to display. First finish the upper row, then start a new row, give buffer of `5 columns` to reach the desired column ie `In the Liquidated Society` and again a buffer of `2 columns`.

You can use `<th colspan="5">` instead of having `five <th>` tags as in my answer.

EDIT:

This is how you will achieve it

```
<table border="1" class="datatable table-striped table-bordered"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th rowspan="2">ID</th>
            <th rowspan="2"> Name of the Liquidated Society</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Jurisdiction of the Society</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Liquidation Order No & Date</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Name & Designation of Liquidator</th>
            <th colspan="6">In the Liquidated Society</th>


            <th rowspan="2">Update</th>
            <th rowspan="2">Delete</th>
        </tr>
         <tr>


              <th>Govt Share</th>
              <th>Govt Loan</th>
              <th>Assets to be recovered</th>
              <th>Liability to be discharged </th>
              <th>Cancellation Order Number and Date </th>
              <th> Surplus amount remitted to CDF</th>

            </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

it will look like this

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ankit, Thanks for replying. Pls see the image i uploaded. I am getting everything proper except last 2 cols. It should also come in the same row as others.

Comment: @kdr you are not getting last columns in the same row as the HTML syntax is wrong. As i have explained in my answer above and what OkoTikashi has also said. You need to have two rows.

Comment: some how in mine same code given by you is not working proper related to border . The border is not coming proper before Update

Comment: @kdr you need to post your CSS too, I cannot help you otherwise.

Comment: I fixed it . It was a CSS bug . Thank You @Ankit